# How to validate exact words in Laravel?

Tags: validation, laravel

Does the validation class in Laravel validate exact words?

eg

```
$rules = [
           "field" => "hello"
         ]
```

Where the value of the field must be "hello".

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes. I know of at least two ways.

```
// option one: 'in' takes a comma-separated list of acceptable values
$rules = [
    'field' => 'in:hello',
];

// option two: write a matching regular expression
$rules = [
    'field' => 'regex:^hello$',
];
```

Actually, I don't remember if you need the ^$ delimiters in the regex, but it's easy to find out by trying it. :)

Comment: Thanks, "in" was what I was after.

Answer (score 7):

Method updated for Laravel 5.5.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in

```
// 'in' takes an array of values

$rules = [
    'field' => [ Rule::in('hello')]
];
```

`Use Rule;` namespace in your controller to access Rule class `(Illuminate\Validation\Rule)`