# Laravel - Validate value against string

Tags: laravel

I am running some basic validation inside a Laravel 5.5 controller like this...

```
                   $this->validate($request, [
                        'name' => 'required|max:30',
                        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
                        'password' => 'required|max:20',
                        'mykey' => 'required',
                    ]);
```

Is there a way to check if 'mykey' matches a php string I have saved?  I know I can do an if statement and compare them but wondered if there was a way I could do this inside the validation itself?

Comment: You mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509802/how-to-validate-exact-words-in-laravel/23509885#23509885

Comment: I had looked at 'same' and 'confirm' but hadn't spotted 'in' - Will take a look now, thanks

Comment: Do you mean saved in the database? What should happen if the string is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in) rule, This works for *n* number of values

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:30',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
    'password' => 'required|max:20',
    'mykey' => [
        Rule::in([env('MY_KEY'),config('app.another_key')]),
    ]    
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides a `regex` option for validation. Depending on the complexity of the string comparison it may be useful:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-regex

Answer (score 0):

You can this rule:

```php
$key = "my_saved_key"
$request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:30',
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
    'password' => 'required|max:20',
    'mykey' => 'in:' . $key,
    ]    
]);
```