# Larave validate column to be always unique whatever value is

Tags: php, laravel

So i have table with columns: `id, user_id, value`  value is not always something fixed. if it is for example: `EUR`. all records for `user_id` must be `EUR`. how to validate this maybe in migration?

Comment: I recommend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509802/how-to-validate-exact-words-in-laravel

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Validation Rules https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-rule-objects

```
$request->validate([
    'currency' => ['required', 'string', new CurrencyRule],
]);
```